# Rounding in C without using any math.h functions

Tags: c, variables, rounding

I am new to C, and my first homework assignment has us using C to run an equation off of inputs. The problem I'm running into is that the outputs need to be whole numbers. The equation I came up with for the problem works if every output is rounded up to the next whole number. We cannot use math.h functions like round, ceil, or floor. We can only use stdio.h functions.

I have tried making the output variable both an integer and a float, but neither seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Not really, since you haven't shown your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Relevant code belongs in the question itself (you can edit it). Also -- a code fragment without a clear description of what that fragment is supposed to do isn't very useful in clarifying your problem.

Comment: Welcome! Please do not post links to pictures of text of code. Post the actual code, in the question, as text copy/pasted exactly. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pJmj38X these pictures have my code and an example of the problem in my output

Comment: Sorry: we can't compile pictures.

Comment: I am ***NOT*** going to retype all that code just to help you, especially when you could have copy-pasted it into your question.

Comment: The simplest and easiest way to round in C is probably `(int)(x + 0.5)`, which might be enough to get you started.  If you want to round to something other than the nearest whole number, or if `x` might be negative, or if you want to implement more sophisticated rules like "round to even", you'll need something more elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not sufficiently clear, and you did not provide any specific input/output examples.

But here's my attempt at what I think you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// May return 0, -1 or +1
int sign(int x)
{
    return (x>0)-(x<0);
}

typedef struct
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    char* test_name;
} testcase_t;

int main(void) {
    testcase_t tests[] = {
        { 1,  2, "+0.5 Rounded to 1"  },
        {23, 10, "2.3 Rounded to 2"   },
        {-1,  2, "-0.5 Rounds to -1"  },
        {-1, -2, "0.5 (double negative) rounds to +1" }
    };
    
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(tests)/sizeof(*tests); ++i)
    {
        int numerator  = tests[i].numerator;
        int denominator = tests[i].denominator;
        char* name = tests[i].test_name;
        
        // Calculate integer division, with rounding away from zero. 
        // eg. -2.6 rounds to -3; +2.6 rounds to +3 (always "away" from zero)
        // using only integer operations
        int result = (numerator + sign(numerator)*sign(denominator)*denominator/2) / denominator;
        
        printf("Test: %0.3f ==> %d (%s)\n", (float)numerator/denominator, result, name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```